# Improving (Android - Release) performance in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Are there any tips and tricks I could apply to improve the performance of a  React Native Android build?

I'm already applying things like

- Removing console logs.
- No inline styles.
- Not calling setState on an unmounted component.

But that's just not enough ... cause when I compare my ios build to the android one ... there's a huge performance gap, unfortunately.

Does that have to do with a specific React Native version?

any help is very much appreciated...

Comment: Where are you witnessing performance issues? Is it related to navigation, animations, ... ?

Comment: the app's reponse to touches for example, in ios version it's super fast, unlike android one, there's a little bit of time gap between the `touch` and the actual response

Comment: I think it depends on the android version and device, Because it's different to test your application on marshmallow android version and Android Q version, While IOS are mostly more powerful and updated devices.